# Update the YEAR on a DATE field

Tags: date, db2, zos, db2-zos

DB2 z/OS Version 10

For a `DATE` column in a table I would like to update the YEAR portion of the `DATE` to 1900. For example, update `1981-09-03` to `1900-09-03`.

I have attempted using the following:

```
 UPDATE SERDB.S16_WEB_USERS_T
       SET YEAR(S16_BIRTH_DT) = '1900'
     WHERE YEAR(S16_BIRTH_DT) > '0';
```

I receive the following error:

> ILLEGAL SYMBOL "(". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: = ..
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.67.27 SQL Code: -104, SQL
>   State: 42601

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't use `YEAR()` to set a value in a date field in any platform or version of DB2.

Going to have to do some math

```
 UPDATE SERDB.S16_WEB_USERS_T
       SET S16_BIRTH_DT = S16_BIRTH_DT - (YEAR(S16_BIRTH_DT) - 1900) YEARS 
     WHERE YEAR(S16_BIRTH_DT) > '0';
```

But I question why you want to do this.  Especially with the `WHERE YEAR(S16_BIRTH_DT) > '0'`.

Also note that if the birthdate is on the 29th of February, the date will be changed to the 28th of February 1900.

Comment: Thank you so much!